# trying the rails model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm not sure if this a best practices in terms of association. Anyone can help me

```
//post,rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :location, through: :user
  has_one :category, through: :user
  has_one :type, through: :user
end

//user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

//category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end

//location.rb
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end

//type.rb
class Typo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

So the one of main goal of this are it's like 
User.posts.location,create(country: "Japan", city: "Kyoto")

but i get an error with location NoMethodError: undefined method `location' for #

also should i a references in post like `location:references type:references category:references`

Comment: You have 3 classes `Category`, let them different names.

Comment: sorry edited i just made a copy paste

Comment: Please add migration file also.

Comment: i already fixed this and yeah what i do is i remove the through in every has one

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename the classes like

```
#location.rb
class Location< ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :post
end

#type.rb
class Type < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :post
end
```

Not need to

```
through: :user #=> this use for many to many relationship
```

You can remove this